# Assets not found Rails on Webrick thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datatables, thin, webrick

I'm running my rails WEBrick server with 'thin' gem for minimal logging in development mode.
I use [data tables](http://datatables.net/) to show some tables on my html page. But I get errors with assets:

> Started GET "/app/assets/images/sort_both.png" for 127.0.0.1 at
> 2012-11-24 20:14:45 -0800 2012-11-24 20:14:45 -- 
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
> "/app/assets/images/sort_both.png")

I have made sure that the image in the folder exists.

I have changed the config in config/environments/development.rb for WEBrick to be able to serve static content with:

> config.serve_static_assets = true

I can't figure out what's going on. Could somebody please help me on this?

Cheers,
ANi

Comment: did you restart server ?

Comment: there's a railscasts on this theme: http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables try it out

Comment: The railscast mentioned above is extremely outdated at this point. Do not expect much of the code to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs are saying you're asking for the wrong url. Usually `/app` isn't part of the http request. Make sure you're using `asset_path` in your views.

I also bet a GET request to `/assets/images/sort_both.png` would work.